# jQuery - Move element inside a sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move an element to a sibling.

I the example below, I want to move all `.i-want-to-be-your-child` elements to be inside the sibling `.come-to-me`.

**Original HTML**

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="come-to-me">Welcome!</a>
  <span class="i-want-to-be-your-child">Thank you!</span>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" class="come-to-me">Welcome!</a>
  <span class="i-want-to-be-your-child">Thank you!</span>
</div>
```

**I want the end result to be**

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="come-to-me">Welcome!<span class="i-want-to-be-your-child">Thank you!</span></a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" class="come-to-me">Welcome!<span class="i-want-to-be-your-child">Thank you!</span></a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.i-want-to-be-your-child').detach().appendTo($(sibling('.come-to-me')));
  //$('.i-want-to-be-your-child').appendTo($(this).parent().child('.come-to-me'));
});
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to achieve this?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/graphic_dev/9ajhqnzz/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the syntax somewhat mixed up. Just append it, and it will move

```
$('.come-to-me').append(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.i-want-to-be-your-child');
});
```

```js
  $('.come-to-me').append(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.i-want-to-be-your-child');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="come-to-me">Welcome!</a>
  <span class="i-want-to-be-your-child">Thank you!</span>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" class="come-to-me">Welcome!</a>
  <span class="i-want-to-be-your-child">Thank you!</span>
</div>
```